# How do I execute a foreach lambda expression on ObservableCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, silverlight, observablecollection

How do I execute a `foreach` lambda expression on ObservableCollection<T>?

There is not method of `foreach` with ObservableCollection<T> although this method exists with List<T>.

Is there any extension method available?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no method available by default in the BCL but it's straight forward to write an extension method which has the same behavior (argument checking omitted for brevity)

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action) {
  foreach ( var cur in enumerable ) {
    action(cur);
  }
}
```

Use case

```
ObservableCollection<Student> col = ...;
col.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name));
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, this is working great.
but i would like to know one thing that how the predicate is working as an action?
predicated: x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name)

Comment: earlier i was using like this,

statuses.ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsHidden = true);

and i think it was just memory consuming.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var e in enumerable)
        {
            action(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
observableCollection.ToList().ForEach( item => /* do something */);
```