# ForEach error in a observablecollection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, foreach, win-universal-app, observablecollection

I have a problem with the **ForEach** in an observablecollection. Visual Studio tells me:

*"The 'observablecollection' does not contain a 'ForEach' definition and was not found at the 'ForEach' extension method that accepts a first 'observablecollection' type argument. Probably missing a directive using or reference to the assembly"*.

The problem is that, the similar code in another project, works fine but in this new project not. Where am I wrong?

Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProvaBindingXaml
{
   /* public class Impiegato
    {

        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Cognome { get; set; }
        public string Matricola { get; set; }

    }
    */

    public class Rule
    {
        public string Ruolo { get; set; }

        public Rule(string ruolo)
        {
            this.Ruolo = ruolo;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Ruolo;
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<Rule> GetAllRules()
        {
            var CollectionRuoli = new ObservableCollection<Rule>();
            CollectionRuoli.Add(new Rule ("Impiegato"));
            CollectionRuoli.Add(new Rule ("Dirigente"));
            CollectionRuoli.Add(new Rule ("Operaio"));
            CollectionRuoli.Add(new Rule ("Manutentore"));
            CollectionRuoli.Add(new Rule ("Presidente"));
            return CollectionRuoli;

        }


        public static void GetComboBoxList(ObservableCollection<Rule> RuleItems)
        {
            var allItems = GetAllRules();
            RuleItems.Clear();
            allItems.ForEach(p => RuleItems.Add(p));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2519433/316799

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` does not have a `ForEach` method.

I suspect you may be thinking of `List`'s [ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) - but `List` is a different type.

I would consider using a `foreach` loop, or call `ToList` before using `ForEach`.

Comment: ok but why this code, that it is in another project, works?
https://s13.postimg.org/rhyiw3vkn/Immagine.png

Comment: In that other project, go to the `ForEach` line and right click and `Go To Implementation`. My guess is someone has written an extension method there, but you'd need to check and confirm to us.

Comment: yes: there is this code
`namespace WinRTXamlToolkit.Tools
{
    public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action);
        public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list);
    }
}`


Oh, I think that I understood!!! Thank you

Comment: Well, that is why it works there and not in yours. Also check the links that myself and Felipe have provided against your original post.